# Why calendar constant is showing in codenameone?

Tags: calendar, codenameone

[image]I want to customize calendar by using theme contact in designer but i did not find the constants for calendar in theme which is shown in attached image And I have looked in chrome demo app and i found that there caledarleftimage ,calTitleDaystyleBool and many more . How to get these contanst in my app?

And how can i use this codenameone-calendar in my project ?
[https://code.google.com/p/codenameone-calendar/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIzlo.png)

I have used designer but I did not fine the caledarleftimage constant

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the constants into the UI, its an editable combo box that allows entering anything you want.

Comment: In designer I did not fine the caledarleftimage constant,calTitleDaystyleBool and many more 
why is this happening?

Comment: You can type in these constants. Constants can be defined by anyone (including you) so the combo box just lists common well known constants.

Comment: Thank shai 
i am able to create my own constants in designer and now I  did not understand what are the uses of these user defined constants ?
What are different between these user defined contstants and already defined constants?

Comment: You can set them to a different value, you can add additional constants e.g. the codenameone-calendar is a 3rd party calendar and it can rely on constants that we aren't aware of. This allows customizing things from the theme rather than the code which is often more convenient.